# react redux router url change but shows the same page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux

I have this code in my `redux actions`:

```
import { push } from 'redux-router';
import {LOGIN} from '../constants/login'
export function login(){

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        var message = "Welcome"
        dispatch({ message, type: LOGIN })
        console.log(getState())
        return dispatch(push('/login'))
    }
}
```

and in my component I have like :

```
<button className={"ui red large button"} type="button" onClick={this.props.actions.login}>LOG IN</button>
```

Here I am using `redux router`.

My url changes in browser but it still shows the same page.. 
Url is changed but it shows the same page.. Is it issue with my browser or anything else I am missing in here ..

Thank you..

Comment: Can you check the click event is captured or not? I guess, you need to bind the click event

Comment: I am calling an action on click.. and It is working.. I have printed some value on console on from action

Comment: As per the doc, it just changes address bar location https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router#pushlocation.. Can you try with pushState, `dispatch(pushState(null, '/path'));`. I found this from https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example